# linphone make install command is giving error: liblinphone-sdk:copyAssets FAILED

Tags: android, linphone, linphone-sdk

I am working on liblinePhone sdk for voice and video calling in android app.

and follow all step which is mentioned in git for build projects and make the build.

I call `make install` and getting error like:

```
Task :liblinphone-sdk:copyAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: path may not be null or empty string. path=''
```

I checked by echo $PATH , echo $ANDROID_HOME and echo $JAVA_HOME all path are set properly.

I am using android studio 3.1.3 and ubantu.

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Yes,you are right I have also got same error while install this. Really this library is too much complicated. I need help any one have proper solutiin please?.